# Fourier analysis on crystallographic groups

Tags: harmonic-analysis, gr.group-theory, nt.number-theory

It seems pretty clear *a priori* that Fourier analysis on a  discrete cocompact group of motions of $\mathbb{E}^n$ should be quite tractable (since, by Bieberbach, such groups are almost $\mathbb{Z}^n,$ but I have not seen a lucid exposition of such, so any pointers or words of wisdom would be welcome.

Comment: I don't too much about this area, but I think the jump is not quite as small as one might first hope. That said, one place to start with some aspects of their Fourier analysis might be with a description of their $C^*$-algebras, for which this paper of K. F. Taylor http://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~kft/ResearchRelated/C_star_crystal.pdf could be worth a look.

Comment: The finite dimensional reps are given here: http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Crystallographic_group

Comment: I will check these out, thanks to both @Yemon and @Mrc...